# JavaScript define function to take outer function parameter

Tags: javascript

I want to define a function:

```
const f = (outside, param1, param2) => {
  outside(param1, param2);
}
```

But I know this function will always be called inside a function which has outside as parameter. For example:

```
const g = (outside, param3, param4) => {
  // some code here

  f(outside, var1, var2);

  // some more code
}
```

Is there any way to define `f` so that I dont need to pass `outside` to it when calling inside `g`?

Also I want to be able to call `f` inside other functions who take `outside` as parameter, not just `g`.

Comment: If `f` is local to `g`, why not define it inside `g` in which case it can use `g`'s arguments?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't want it to be local. I want to be able to call f inside g1, g2, g3 and so on.

Comment: make it local. Define a shortcut to `f` inside `g` and let the `f` be.

Comment: You could use bind to save yourself passing outside, are you calling f a lot of times, as just passing outside once using bind would be overkill.

Comment: In order to get a more useful answer than "it's not possible" you should explain why you want to do this and provide more information about what the functions are doing. Maybe changing how the functions call each other would help. But with such a sparse example there is not much to go on. This is basically an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to define `f` so that I dont need to pass `outside` to it when calling inside `g`?

No. You are asking for [*dynamic scope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scope) but JavaScript uses [*lexical scope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope). That means the availability/visibility of symbols is determined by the way functions are *defined*, not how/when/where they are called.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of the arguments and take action depending on their existence:

```js
const f = (param1, param2, outside) => {
  if (outside) {
    outside(param1, param2);
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately a function defined outside of function g, will not have direct access to the variables contained in function g. For this reason, you must necessarily pass the parameter outside to function f.

Comment: The thing is, I know I will always call f inside a function which has outside as parameter, so no need to check.

Comment: @Ghost OK, the way I understood it was that you want to have flexibility and use a function once with a parameter and once without. Unfortunately a function defined outside of function g, will not have direct access to the variables contained in function g. For this reason, you must necessarily pass the parameter outside to function f.

Answer (score 0):

And if you change your logic like this? Will it fit your needs?

```js
// Set function logic
const f = (param1, param2) => {
  return param1 + param2;
}

// Outside method
const outside = v => {
  console.log(`I'm outside: ${v}`);
}

// Call from outside logic
const g = (outside, param3, param4) => {
  // If you know, that it is outside wrapper, wrap it here
  outside(f(param3, param4));
}
g(outside, 2, 2);

// Call from else logic
console.log(`I'm else logic: ${f(3, 3)}`);
```